# Why (or when) would my app get reset by iOS?

Tags: ios, reset, null

Is there any reason that my app would get reset entirely by the iPhone?

I have a timer app that has timers with notifications for each timer. Occasionally, (it may be related to charging the phone) the app gets reset entirely, all timers stopped and reset as if the app had never been run before.

Is there a time when apps get a call to nil-out? Should I be storing the timer start times and a BOOL saying a timer is running in NSUserDefaults (or similar)?

Thanks in advance,

Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications can be killed at ***any time*** both by the OS and the user, thus leaving us developers in a constant state of worry about hard data like yours.  If you must, save it to an NSUserDefault for the next launch of your app.

Comment: Where is the best place to save and then restore this data? applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidEnterForeground?

Comment: It's good practice to save data after certain actions or methods are called (user presses Save or sets up a new timer). You would also save in the `applicationWillTerminate` method in the App Delegate. Note: You'll only have a few seconds to save the data, which is why it is good for you to save data when the app is in use (At least you won't lose everything).

Comment: In my current application, for example (a book style app where users flip to different pages), I save on each page turn, and in appWillEnterBackground and appWillTerminate (last one is probably not needed since the user can't terminate the app while it is in the foreground as far as I know but just being safe)

Comment: Great tips, thanks all. It looks like Apple recommends applicationDidEnterBackground: as a good spot for me to stop my timers and save settings. So I guess I will save the settings there in NSUserDefaults, then use those to restore my app when applicationDidBecomeActive: gets called.

Comment: ***EDIT*** It looks like I will need to save settings at applicationWillResignActive as well in order for this to work, as this method gets called in most of the situations where the app is no longer active in the foreground.